# ODBC tools for MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, odbc, panel, admin

We have ROR site with a MySQL database. There are many tables which we would like read/write access to, but we have not written this function within our current admin panel. I was curious the drawbacks of using an ODBC tool to perform all reading/writing of values to the database from the admin panel. Also, does anyone have any suggestions for ODBC tools that we should look into for an easy to use software.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you haven't actually started using Rails, else you wouldn't ask this question. Go spend some time reading the documentation and a few getting started tutorials.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Rails comes out of the box with ActiveRecord, an ORM layer. Once you get familiar with it, reading/writing to the database will be a breeze, independent of what database you are using.